# Convert Array to formatted Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array which looks as below

```
array = [
        'NAME          STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION',
        'master0.com   Ready    master   4d17h   v1.14.6+0a21dd3b3',
        'master1.com   Ready    master   4d17h   v1.14.6+0a21dd3b3'
        ]
```

The data in above Array including the headers is dynamic. I would like to know the best approach to covert into a hash which looks like follows

```
        [{'NAME': 'master.com',
          'STATUS': 'Ready',
          'ROLES': 'master'},
         {'Name': 'master2.com',
          'STATUS': 'Ready',
          'ROLES': 'master'}
        ]
```

I'm also posting a solution which does work, but I'm sure there is a best and better approach to do this please suggest.

Any help with this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module with some pre-formatting to be able to use [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read every row as a dict.

try this:

```py
import csv
from io import StringIO

txt_as_csv = StringIO('\n'.join(','.join(row.split()) for row in array))
reader = csv.DictReader(txt_as_csv)
result = [row for row in reader]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works with nested for loop. But solution with less complexity is accepted.

```py
            key_list = array[0].split()
            dict = {}
            result = []

            for content in array[1:len(array)]:
                details = content.split()
                for i in range(len(key_list)):
                    dict[key_list[i]] = details[i]
                result.append(dict)
```